# Prevent Play template engine from escaping JavaScript quotation marks

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0, escaping

I want to include a Facebook post using a template from the Play framework. The Problem is that, even though `@Html` should not escape HTML entities, they get escaped. As a result `"` turns into `&quot;` and the script is not evaluated.

**Embed-Code**

```
post = "<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) { 
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id; 
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1"; 
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151945402933553" data-width="466">
  <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151945402933553">Beitrag</a> von <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers">Facebook Developers</a>.
  </div>
</div>"`
```

**Template** `@Html(post)`

**Output**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) { 
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
      js = d.createElement(s); 
      js.id = id; 
      js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&quot;;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, &apos;script&apos;, &apos;facebook-jssdk&apos;));
</script>
<div class="fb-post"; data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151945402933553" data-width="466">
   <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151945402933553">Beitrag</a> von <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers">Facebook Developers</a>.
   </div>
 </div>
```

I'm really stuck, because `@Html()` is not doing what it's supposed to do [according to the doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0-M1/ScalaTemplates).

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code because `@Html` works fine, even with javascript. I know your Embed-Code section got edited for "formatting" even though it technically breaks it. Please show how you are setting the embed-code and passing it to your view. That might shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works exactly as the docs says, try this out for example:
Template:

```
@()
@Html("<div>&\"</div>")
```

Will give you this output:

```
<div>&"</div>
```

So there must be something else going on in your app that html-escapes the string.

Comment: It does work fine with plain HTML, but still, all JavaScript code within the script tags gets html-escaped and therefore invalid.

Comment: Changing the raw string to "<script>&\"</script>" still gives the correct output. There is something else going on, either your string is not what you think it is or you look at the result the wrong way (dom-tree in your browser debugger rather than source for example)

Comment: Alright, I'll keep on trying. Thanks for your help!